# beta reduction: correct way to replace bound variables?

Tags: lambda-calculus

say I have the following example of a lambda expression with `\x` meant to represent lambda x

What would the beta reduction of the following be?

```
(\x.\x.(x x)) \z.z
```

My first instinct would have been for this to be

```
\x.(\z.z \z.z)
```

But someone I spoke with was of the opinion that the second \x would also be replaced with `\z.z`

which would mean it is really

```
\(\z.z).(\z.z \z.z)
```

Can someone please clarify what the correct approach would be. I can't say I really understand the second approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `(\x.\x.(x x)) \z.z` is alpha equivalent to `(\x.\y.(y y)) \z.z` because variables are always bound to the closest lambda abstraction.

This means `(\x.\x.(x x)) \z.z` is beta equivalent to `\x.(x x)`.

Substitution is never done on lambda abstractions, the `\x.` part.

Comment: Rui thank you for the response. I had that feeling, any chance you might have a reference to a website/textbook that might highlight the  "never substitute on lambda abstraction" part? I'd like to share that with them so that we're all on the same page. Thanks!

Comment: Beta reduction is defined in terms of substitution, so [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Capture-avoiding_substitutions) and [here, page 8](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~slonnegr/plf/Book/Chapter5.pdf).